# Kik requirements to application load time

Tags: kik

Our application is a full-featured game the should load ~15MB of assets, mainly graphics and sounds (PNGs are already optimized with tinyPNG, sounds are MP3/OGG with average bitrate).

So, the game load time is far great than 4000ms (first time). But the game has a nice (honest) loading progress bar.

Will it be indexed and pass through Kik QA?
If no, what are recommendations for such "heavy" applications?

Thanks,
Sergey.

---

From Kik requirements:
"
The webpage should always be fast to load.
Use minification to accomplish this, aim to be 4000ms on first visit, 700 ms on repeat visits.

Webpage should not consume excessive amounts of data on load.
Load the webpage and with no interaction should never go above 2MB
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load time recommendations are referring to how long it takes for the window.onload event to fire.

Based km what you said, your game will be fine because it loads quickly but then implements its own in-game loading state to load assets.

Comment: I want to clearup this requirement anyway:
"aim to be 4000ms on first visit, 700 ms on repeat visits."

What connection speed is used to test this?
Because 2Mb download via good Wi-Fi is not the same as 2Mb download via not-so-good 3G.